# How to launch multiple test servers in a Django unittest

Tags: python, django

How would you simulate the running of multiple test servers in a Django unittest?

I have a common code-base that powers two different sites with a separate database and `settings.py` file. I'm trying to unittest a tool that imports data from one site to another.

The default unittest setup supports multiple sqlite3 databases, so I can confirm the data on one site gets into the other's database, but I'm not sure how to confirm the data in the UI on the other site, since the default client only seems to support a single server/port.

Answer (score 0):

You probably no longer need an answer to this question

I think for your specific case you don't need to have multiple servers, just multiple tests - first testing that the output from the exporting server meets your assumption, and second testing that this assumed output is successfully imported into the database. In Django unit tests the database will be empty at the start of each test

You can generate large datasets in Django using [Django Fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/initial-data/). Worth noting as you should consider whether you can use their existing tools for the export/import